# Generate Timestamp after converting to UTC Date

Tags: java, oracle, groovy

I am trying to insert `datetime` string value in Oracle Table on Timestamp(6) column.

But I am getting `ORA-01843: not a valid month` error.

Is there a way to this groovy specific **without** specifying oracle functions like `to_date` or `to_timestamp`?

```
2017-12-15 14:39:45
```

Comment: `2017-12-15 14:39:45` has nothing to do with "UTC Date". This is just the format according (or more precisely *similar*) to [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Yes I agree. Actually the datetime was `2017-12-15 15:39:45+01:00` and converted and so I mentioned as UTC Date

Comment: I am not familiar with groovy but what about prepared statements and bind variables? Then the date format  should not matter at all.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, Yes in groovy there is no such option like in Java to specify `setDate` with `PreparedStatement` :(

Comment: @DON Each database has its own driver in Java.  I don't know Groovy, but the best option here would probably be to detect the database and then use the right interface.  Even if Wernfred's solution works for Oracle, what about other databases?

Comment: MySQL accepts date literals according to ISO-8601 by default. However, there are other RDBMS (e.g. SQL Server) which do not accept the ISO format by default or without explicit conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set session parameter:

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

After you set this parameter you can enter your date as text string.

You can set these values also as Environment variable or in your Registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%`, resp `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%`

Comment: Won't there be any way at Java end itself?

Comment: Good question, I don't know. Most likely Java does not read the Windows registry in order to be platform independent. However, I assume setting environment variable should work.

Comment: Please avoid verbose comments under my answer.  Your latest comment said nothing, added nothing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `TO_TIMESTAMP`:

```
SELECT
    TO_TIMESTAMP ('2017-12-15 14:39:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
FROM DUAL;
```

### Demo

Comment: @DON I read correctly.  The standard way to convert text into a timestamp is via `TO_TIMESTAMP`.  There is nothing wrong with using it, but rather you should not be storing dates as text in the first place.

Comment: I don't know the reason but in the question it was explicitly stated that he/she looks for a solution without `TO_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit We are not limited to answering only based on what the OP says.

Comment: Thanks! Why I have to do this java/groovy specific is, my database differs between environments like `MySQL` and `OracleDB`. So obviously `to_timestamp` won't work in MySQL So without writing different code blocks, I want to handle this is groovy specific

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit You would assume many things.  Interacting with each database via a script should be platform specific.  Java has ORM tools for this, but the OP is not using them.